# Floating balls position set (vector2d?)

Tags: java, android, collision

Okay. My problem is kinda mind-blowing. Let's say that I have a constructor which looks like this:

```
  public Ball(Random r, float halfphonewidth, float halfphoneheight, float cx, float cy){
    //te wartosci odpowiadaja za losowe polozenie i losowe wektory
    x = (halfphonewidth-48)*0.1f;
    y = (halfphoneheight-48)*0.1f;
    vx = -0.2f + r.nextFloat();
    vy = -0.2f + r.nextFloat();

    Log.i("", "\n\n" + this.vx + "  " +this.vy+"\n\n");
    health = 3;
}
```

Now let's say that I have a step() method declared somewhere - it works. Step:

```
 public void step(){
    x += vx;
    y += vy;

    if(x<2f || x > 98f)
        vx =- vx;


    if(y<2f || y > 98f)
        vy =- vy;
}
```

I have an onTouch event that listens and checks the 'click coords'. I catch them and pass to the constructor (float cx, float cy).

The first position of the ball is static - I set it permanently in the constructor and move by 48 pixels (cause of image size). It starts from the bottom-center and floats to the random direction + when it collides with a wall it reverses it's vx & vy.

So! I need to point the ball in a direction I click! :D
I tried by scaling screen w/h with coordinate system, tried with implementing Vector2D class (cause it's missing in the newest java I think) but im not that good with linear algebra, tried with trygonometry(even cyclometry) (but I may be blind).

Is there anyone that can point me a solution? Which is the best way and which should I try to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the difference between the coordinates of the current position and the click position:

```
double xDiff = clickPoint.x - ball.x;
double yDiff = clickPoint.y - ball.y;
```

then you move the ball with a velocity proportional to that difference, in your case you have to set the `vx` and `vy` like:

```
vx = xDiff * n;
vy = yDiff * n;
```

where the bigger `n` is, the faster the ball will reach the target. You need to update the `xDiff` and `yDiff` variables as the ball move, so when the difference is 0 the movement will stop.